# Delete Elements is disabled after Select All

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

I came across a peculiar behavior on SharePoint 2013.

My list captures some dummy records when the user encounters any issue during a form submission.

I was trying to delete these records.

In the `All Items` view, if I select only the records from the yesterday, `Delete Elements` is enabled.
If I select a record from the previous day also, `Delete Elements` gets disabled.

screenshots below:
[image: Delete is enabled]

[image: Delete is disabled]

When I created a new view for seeing only these records, `Delete Elements` stays enabled.

What is this restriction in SharePoint?

Comment: do you have enough rights to delete that the entry from previous day?

Comment: @DamjanTomic I am an Site collection admin, and as already mentioned in the original question, I am able to delete after creating a new View.